# Trouble while including gradle dependency for zuul

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

This is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'yBayApplication'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = "com.ybayApplication.customerAccount.CustomerServiceApplication"
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server:1.2.3.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zuul')
    compile group: 'com.netflix.zuul', name: 'zuul-core', version: '2.0.0-rc.1'
    compile group: 'com.netflix.governator', name: 'governator-archaius', version: '1.6.0'
    compile group: 'io.reactivex', name: 'rxjava-string', version: '0.22.0'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Brixton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}
```

And this is the error message, I am receiving while building the gradle.

```
Gradle Distribution: Local installation at C:\gradle\gradle-3.4.1
Gradle Version: 3.4.1
Java Home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Gradle Tasks: clean build

:clean UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':detachedConfiguration5'.
> Could not find com.netflix.governator:governator-archaius:1.6.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/netflix/governator/governator-archaius/1.6.0/governator-archaius-1.6.0.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/netflix/governator/governator-archaius/1.6.0/governator-archaius-1.6.0.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/com/netflix/governator/governator-archaius/1.6.0/governator-archaius-1.6.0.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/com/netflix/governator/governator-archaius/1.6.0/governator-archaius-1.6.0.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/netflix/governator/governator-archaius/1.6.0/governator-archaius-1.6.0.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/netflix/governator/governator-archaius/1.6.0/governator-archaius-1.6.0.jar
  Required by:
      project :
      project : > com.netflix.zuul:zuul-core:2.0.0-rc.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
Total time: 1.77 secs
```

As you can see in the build.gradle file, I have added the missing dependency as well. I am tying to implement a Zuul filter based on this example in gradle https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first look, it looks like you need to remove the
`compile group: 'com.netflix.zuul', name: 'zuul-core', version: '2.0.0-rc.1'`

The `compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zuul')` is dependent on zuul core so it will download it.

Additionally, for the `governator-archaius` I don't see the version 1.6.0. 
I think you meant 1.16.0. Look at the link here to grab the accurate version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.governator/governator-archaius

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Yes it did the trick. But I still wonder why i was getting the error message as version 1.6.0 and not 1.16.0. Anyways, thank you.

Comment: @Adithya because there is no version 1.6.0 they might have gotten rid of the older version if you click on the link above you should see the last version that they have is 1.7.1